# Как считать проценты от числа в js?

Tags: javascript

К примеру:

```
var money = 100000;
var tallage = 35%;// Синтаксическая ошибка
```

При записи знака '%' выдает синтаксическую ошибку. Как действовать в таком случае ?

Comment: Даю подсказку: когда нужно взять 35% от числа - число нужно умножить на 0.35

Comment: И будет выдавать. Это в художественном тексте так пишется, а в JavaScript знак "%" - оператор. В конструкции `35%;` после оператора идет завершение (знак `;`), а браузер ищет там делитель.

Comment: Школьная математика же!

Comment: Ну можно же CSS перепутать с JS. В CSS % практикуется.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Знак процента не пишется в переменных. Его выводят пользователю в виде строки.

```js
var money = 100000;
var tallage = 35;
var result = money / 100 * tallage; //вычисление процентов
console.log(tallage + '% от ' + money + ' будет ' + result);
```

Answer (score 4):

`%` это математическая операция взятия остатка.

Чтобы получить X процентов от Y необходимо воспользоваться следующей формулой:

```
Y * (X / 100)
```

Answer (score 2):

Умножить на десятичную дробь

```js
var money = 100000;
var tallage = 0.35;
console.log(money*tallage);
```

Answer (score 2):

Для просчета процента от числа используется простая формула:

```
число*100/сумма
```

Для записи этой формулы при помощи JavaScript - откроем инспектор браузера и напишем:

```
var something = 500;
var total = 1000;
var percent = something*100/total
```

Теперь чтобы получить результат, напишем имя переменной percent:

```
percent
50
```

Таким образом мы узнали, что 500 - это 50% от 1000.

Попробуем еще раз, заменив 500 на 300 (ожидаем получить 30%):

```
var something = 300;
var percent = something*100/total

percent
30
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var money = 200; // у нас есть деньги;
var tallage = money / 100 * 35; // обычная формула вычисления процента от числа - 35%
alert(tallage); // результат
```